# How to assign all partitions of a kafka topic to a consumer in Python3.6?

Tags: apache-kafka, python-3.6

I am running Python3.6 and python-kafka 1.3.5

I have a kafka topic with partitions 0-15 and they all currently have messages inside of them. I want my consumer to read and pull messages from all the partitions. This is how I am currently trying to do that

```
import kafka
consumer = kafka.KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers='broker1:9092,broker2:9092,broker3:9092', sasl_mechanism='PLAIN', enable_auto_commit=False, group_id="my_test_group", auto_offset_reset='latest',max_poll_records=2000, heartbeat_interval_ms=2000, consumer_timeout_ms=1000)
kafka_partition0 = kafka.TopicPartition('my_topic', 0)
kafka_partition1 = kafka.TopicPartition('my_topic', 1)
kafka_partition2 = kafka.TopicPartition('my_topic', 2)
kafka_partition3 = kafka.TopicPartition('my_topic', 3)
kafka_partition4 = kafka.TopicPartition('my_topic', 4)
kafka_partition5 = kafka.TopicPartition('my_topic', 5)
kafka_partition6 = kafka.TopicPartition('my_topic', 6)
kafka_partition7 = kafka.TopicPartition('my_topic', 7)
kafka_partition8 = kafka.TopicPartition('my_topic', 8)
kafka_partition9 = kafka.TopicPartition('my_topic', 9)
kafka_partition10 = kafka.TopicPartition('my_topic', 10)
kafka_partition11 = kafka.TopicPartition('my_topic', 11)
kafka_partition12 = kafka.TopicPartition('my_topic', 12)
kafka_partition13 = kafka.TopicPartition('my_topic', 13)
kafka_partition14 = kafka.TopicPartition('my_topic', 14)
kafka_partition15 = kafka.TopicPartition('my_topic', 15)
consumer.assign([kafka_partition0, kafka_partition1, kafka_partition2, kafka_partition3, kafka_partition4, kafka_partition5, kafka_partition6, kafka_partition7, kafka_partition8, kafka_partition9, kafka_partition10, kafka_partition11, kafka_partition12, kafka_partition13, kafka_partition14, kafka_partition15])
messages = consumer.poll()
```

However, when I look at the keys in `messages` variable, I can only see messages coming from partitions 7, 11, and 15

Why is this happening?

Comment: that partitions might have more data, it will get there once it completes them

Comment: check the offsets from that partitions in order to see wether they've got less messages or even are empty

Comment: @Deadpool can you clarify a little bit what you mean by "it will get there once it completes them" for me?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a list seems unneccessary (but list-comprehension would make that code much shorter)

That beind said, the basic example in the documentation consumes from all partitions already

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
consumer = KafkaConsumer('my_favorite_topic', bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092', group_id='my_favorite_group'))
for msg in consumer:
    print(msg)
```

> when I look at the keys in messages variable, I can only see messages coming from partitions 7, 11, and 15

How often are you looking? It should cycle between partitions as it consumes.

Does data actually get *produced* in the other patitions? If not, then there is no need to poll data from them

Comment: Yes, I have verified that the producers are pushing messages into the topic because I do see that there is a lag > 0 for each partition. Currently I am manually consuming from the topic because I notice that I am not getting all the expected messages (i'm looking for a very specific key in the messages). What do you mean by "It should cycle between partitions as it consumes"?

Comment: The consumer group will rebalance to handle every partition over time. There's only so many threads that can consume at once. If you know the key, then you can compute the exact partition and don't need to consume from them all